# How do I override CSS on embedded google calendar using ASP.Net/C#?

Tags: google-calendar-api, background-color

Based on my research and the many posts on this subject, I understand that I cannot alter the CSS in the iframe based on the domain tree security policy. However, I am sure (or hope) there has to be a developer out there that has implemented a way to run the iframe locally on their domain and therefor gain access to alter the CSS attributes.

All I need to do is change the calendar grid (array) background and border colors. Please do not tell me you can change the bg-color in the tool, because all that does is change the header. The border is blue and the bg-color of the grid is defaulted to white.

Any direction would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this:
http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2012/04/integrating-google-calendar-with-your-website/
It is described there how to change google calendar css.